# Partial patch in Python with mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

How can I use `mock.patch` on a function, so I have an access to methods `.assert_called` etc. and simultaneously I can still preserve original functionality of the functions?

Here is example code:

```
from unittest import mock

def foo(arg):
    print(arg)

def tested():
    foo('hi')

@mock.patch('__main__.foo')
def test(foo):
    tested()
    foo.assert_called_once()

test()
```

I want it to test if the `foo` function was called just once but I still need it to print `hi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. I have it solved already. I'v just needed to add parameter `side_effect` to the decorator :-)

Like this:

```
@mock.patch('__main__.foo', side_effect=foo)
def test(foo):
    ...
```